# Como impedir que um elemento sobreponha o outro?

Tags: html5, css3

Como impedir que a sobreposição com outros elementos aconteça? Neste caso o título **ACESSO RÁPIDO AOS PRINCIPAIS CANAIS** está sobrepondo ao elemento abaixo **- Areias monazíticas**

Veja exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS:**

```
p.acessorapido{
float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  max-width: 885px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px #C11C05 solid;
}

p.acessorapido span {
  background-color: #C11C05;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: A largura do seu `span` é maior que a do `p`, havendo, então, a quebra de linha. Qual é o resultado esperado? Que a borda lateral vermelha ficasse abaixo apenas de "Principais Canais" sem sobrepor outros conteúdos? Aliás, qual é a função do `float: left` aí?

Comment: Tem vários aspectos a ser considerado ai @Gladison, o ideal seria vc postar também o código HTML para termos certeza do que esta errado. Pelo q eu entendi ele esta flutuando por causa do `float:left` e por isso o elemento de baixo preenche os vazios, sendo que um margin é considerado espaço vazio "preenchível" quando se tem o float. Um `display: block` pode ajudar, ou `inline-block`, ou até um `clear: both` dependendo do caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que vc deva adicionar o float: left ao segundo item também:

```
p.acessorapido{
float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  max-width: 885px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px #C11C05 solid;
}

p.acessorapido span {
  background-color: #C11C05;
  padding:5px;
  float: left;
}
```